# Filtering Tooltip in Kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a tooltip in Kendo UI which I'm trying to filter cells based on their column name, because the standard td:nthchild won't work (users can move columns around). I want to engage the tooltip based on if someone hovers over MY COLUMN NAME'S CELLS. How do I accomplish that in the filter field? Or should I do it in the show function?

```
this.$el.kendoTooltip({
            filter: "th:contains('MY COLUMN NAME')",
            show: function (e) {
              if (this.content.text().length > 0) {
                  this.content.parent().css("visibility", "visible");
              }  
            },
            hide: function(e) {
                this.content.parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
            },
            content: function (e) {

                var target = e.target;
                return $(target).siblings().first().text();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
this.$el.kendoTooltip({
    filter: "thead th:contains('ColumnA')"
});
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ESaFi)

**UPDATE**

As you want to show the tooltip on the row cell based on the column's title, you can't use [`filter`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip#configuration-filter) parameter for that, it is meant to be used to filter only the target element, which is not your case. You will need some programming there, e.g:

```
show: function(e) {
    let index = this.target().index(), // Get hovered element's column index
        columns = grid.getOptions().columns, // Get grid's columns
        column = columns[index]; // Get current column

    // If target TD is not under 'ColumnA', prevent tooltip from being showed
    if (column.title != "ColumnA") {
        this.hide();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ESaFi/4)

Thanks to kendo, you **can't** prevent their own events, so using [`hide()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip#methods-hide) works but the tooltips still opens blinking before it is hidden again, it's possible to catch it opening. Tried using `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` that would a reasonable way to say *"cancel the widget showing"* but with no luck. This was the best I could do.

Comment: Not quite, in that snippet, I would want when someone hovers over "1" in Column1, a tool tip to popup over that cell.

Comment: Thanks! With a little CSS, I was able to get rid of the flickering

Comment: @KillerSmalls nice!! Glad to help.